# Problema con (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "")

Tags: python, visual-studio

Tengo una duda de principiante en python, el problema que tengo es que tengo dos carpetas(db, routers)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que a la hora de llamar a db desde un archivo de routers me salta el error de ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "db"
Ejemplo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cuál es el problema. Cualquier tipo de ayuda seria genial, muchas gracias :).